# my coffeescript file compiles but mocha gives an error

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, mocha.js

I have a project that uses `"coffee-script": "^1.7.1"` in its `package.json`.

The code has this line in it:

```
[{id: id, name: name}, ...] = result.rows
```

This compiles fine using coffeescript version 1.7.1

The problem is that I am trying to use mocha for unit tests and it gives me an error on this line:

```
Parse error on line xyz: Unexpected '...'
```

Apparently mocha uses an older coffeescript. Is there a way to make it work without adjusting the source for mocha?

EDIT:

my `Gruntfile.coffee`:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = ->
  @initConfig
    cafemocha:
      src: ['test/*.coffee']
      options:
        reporter: 'spec'
        ui: 'bdd'

    coffee:
      compile:
        files:
          'lib/mylib.js': ['src/*.coffee']

  @loadNpmTasks 'grunt-cafe-mocha'
  @loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-coffee'

  @registerTask 'default', ['coffee', 'cafemocha']
```

I added `mocha.opts` to the `test` directory:

```
--require coffee-script/register
--compilers coffee:coffee-script/register
--reporter spec
--ui bdd
```

but, still, when I run `grunt`, it gives me the same error. I am new to this environment, and I find it too complicated, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from version `1.7.x` `CoffeeScript` compiler should be explicitly registered (see [change log for version `1.7.0`](http://coffeescript.org/#changelog)).

So, the problem is that CoffeeScript compiler is not registered when you're running your `mocha` tests, so `node.js` treats all your `.coffee` files as `.js` files.

The best possible solution is to specify `--compilers` option for your mocha tests:

```
--compilers coffee:coffee-script/register
```

If you don't want to include it to every `mocha` call, you could set it up using [`mocha.opts` file](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#mocha.opts).

Here are some useful links:

- [issue about it on github](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/1120)
- [reference in `mocha` docs](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#compilers-option)
- [the reason behind this breaking change in CoffeeScript engine](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/2323)

## Update

Looks like your issue is much deeper then I thought.

First, `grunt-cafe-mocha` doesn't respect `mocha.opts` because it's running tests by `require`ing `mocha` as a dependency, instead of calling `mocha` test runner.

So, it would've been enough to add `require('coffee-script/register')` to the top of your gruntfile, if not for [this old grunt issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/911).

In short, grunt uses `coffee-script 1.3.x`, forcing all its tasks to use the same version of coffee. I had the same problem with `grunt-contrib-connect`, being unable to use latest `coffee-script` in my `express` app.

So, the only help I can offer you is a [small grunt task](https://gist.github.com/lbeschastny/04ce1a889c8b698e7e5c) I wrote to solve similar problem in one of my projects. It runs `mocha` in a separate child process, thus completely isolating it from `grunt`.

**N.B.** I had a thought about releasing this task to `npm`, but considered it too minor.

Comment: thanks! I am still having the same problem. Please see my update.